# Can Twilio send SMSs to a short number?

Tags: api, twilio

Does anyone knows whether Twilio can send an SMS to a short number? By *short number*, I mean a phone number like 1515 or 1414. There is nothing to be found in their docs.

Comment: Have you attempted this? If so, did you get any kind of error?

Comment: They have a section https://www.twilio.com/sms/shortcodes but  am also not able to find out how to send message to some short code number 
like in my case i wanted to send to 281

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately Twilio cannot send SMS messages to short codes:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-my-twilio-number-send-sms-to-a-non-twilio-short-code

Hope that helps.